# cshtml file not refreshed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following a tutorial on Core MVC and hit a wall I can't pierce through.

- I had a `index.html` file
- I have copied index.html file to `Views/Home/index.cshtml`
- Into the cshtml file I have added a simple Razor code: `@DateTime.Now.Year`
- Saved, ran app, default page displays code that looks like `index.html`. `/home` runs cshtml file.
- Not sure why, deleted the `index.html`
- Still the same, default page displays something that looks like `index.html`, `/home` displays `index.cshtml`, despite `index.html` **not even being inside solution anymore**.

My home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Inside my startup file:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("default",
            "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

- [cshtml source with code added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQOi6.jpg)
- [app cshtml source from default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WzBr.jpg)
- [app cshtml source from /home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hVJX.jpg)

Comment: It not clear what you are asking. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I am trying to display a view containing a cshtml file, yet it keeps on showing me a html file that I have already deleted from solution.

Comment: does index.html still exist in the same path? maybe that's what's being served?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

before `app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Configure` method.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-a-default-document) for more details.

in **ASP.Net Core**:

if you do not explicitly use `UseDefaultFiles()` before `UseStaticFiles()` method, 
it will use the `UseStaticFiles()` only which will cause the default page to run all the time and not your index page.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I changed some stuff you guys proposed could work, nothing changed, suddenly something kicked in and it now works fine, even if I revert code back to what it was at the moment of me creating this question.